# Taurus YAML Runtime Property Change for JMeter

Tags: jmeter, yaml

I am trying to invoke Jmeter script with user defined properties with YAML which I am able to change and execute with below configuration.

However if the test started and I need to increase the user on any thread - without stopping the test, how can I achieve that? Let's say the test was started with **Thread1** value as 30 and now if I need to change it to 50 dynamically on runtime. I did not find a way myself. Please advise.

```
    execution:
    - #concurrency: ${__P(my_conc,3)}    # use `my_conc` prop or default=3 if property isn't found
      ramp-up: 1
      hold-for: ${__P(my_hold,1)}
      scenario: simple

    modules:
      jmeter:
        properties:
          my_hold: 60
          
    scenarios:
      simple:
        variables:
          #User DEFINED variable
          Sampler1 : TestSampler1
          Sampler2 : TestSampler2
        script: SampleYAMLJMeter.jmx
        properties:
            #Thread Level variable
            thread1 : 30
            thread2 : 45
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add the following [global JMeter properties](https://gettaurus.org/docs/JMeter/#JMeter-Properties-and-Variables):

   ```
    modules:
      jmeter:
        properties:
          beanshell.server.port: 9000
          beanshell.server.file: ../extras/startup.bsh
   ```
2. Create the `setconc.bsh` file under `.bzt/jmeter-taurus/x.x.x/lib` folder and put the following code into it:

   ```
    org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils.setProperty("my_conc", args[0]);
   ```
3. That's it, whenever you need to change the concurrency of your tests just execute the following command from the `.bzt/jmeter-taurus/x.x.x/lib` folder:

   ```
    java -jar bshclient.jar localhost 9000 setconc.bsh 1234
   ```

   replace `1234` with the actual concurrency you want to achieve

More information:

- [Beanshell server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server)
- [How to Change JMeter´s Load During Runtime](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-change-jmeters-load-during-runtime)

Comment: Thanks @Dmitri-t. I am not able to reduce or increase the properties of my_conc which is defined at concurrency keyword. However my question was if I had to increase a specific thread group - **thread1** in my above example. How can that be changed on runtime from YAML?